# How to restore a MySQL dump file by Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I backup my MySQL databse to a specific folder, say, `d:\backup\` by a webpage. The backup goes without issues, but I am not able to restore it using the following command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u root -p root sgapp <  D:/backup/bkup.sql");
```

What is the cause and how can I solve this?

Comment: Read this: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html All 4 pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DBNAME <  D:/backup/bkup.sql");
```

Mind the *lack of* gap between -p and password string.

Comment: @pheonix4eva -- that was an obvious error. But, I think you should also include the stack trace of the error that you getting when you try from JSP. That will help to dig any deeper.

Comment: i tried try
  {
runtime.exec("mysql  -uroot -proot dd  < D:/backup/bkup.sql");
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
but i get no error

Comment: @Nishant - big mistake - if you are going to use redirection, you have to exec via `cmd.exe` ... I think.

Comment: @Stephen C I was wondering the same, but can't do a quick POC right now. :) our jobs.

Answer (score 1):

That works for me:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start mysqldump -u root -ptestpsw workone -rscript_name.sql");
```

use `-rfilename.sql` instead of redirect < .
Maybe it works for you too.